# Time system when using tf2 lookupTransform

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Given I have a topic `/tf` in rosbag, I want to run the rosbag and use `lookupTransform` to get transform between different frames. The most usual way to get latest transform is `lookupTransform("target_frame", "source_frame", rospy.Time(0))`. What time system does the function `lookupTransform` use, does this function use the wall clock time of the computer calling the function `lookupTransform`, or does it use the timestamp in rosbag. Also, is there any difference when using `lookupTransform("target_frame", "source_frame", rospy.Time(0))` and `lookupTransform("target_frame", "source_frame", rospy.Time())`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/417104/time-system-when-using-tf2-lookuptransform/) by [hck007](https://answers.ros.org/users/96442/hck007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2023-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As [mintar](https://answers.ros.org/question/242154/time-from-rostime0-to-rostimenow/?answer=242157#post-id-242157) puts it:

> The value of `ros::time::now()` depends on whether the parameter `use_sim_time` is set.

> 1. If `use_sim_time == false`, `ros::time::now()` gives you system time (seconds since 1970-01-01 0:00, so something like > 1471868323.123456).
> 2. If `use_sim_time == true`, and you play a `rosbag, ros::time::now()` gives you the time when the rosbag was recorded (probably also something like 1471868323.123456).
> 3. If `use_sim_time == true`, and you run a simulator like Gazebo, `ros::time::now()` gives you the time from when the simulation was started, starting with zero (so probably something like 63.123456 if the simulator has been running for 63.123456 seconds).

So in your case if you want the nodes to use the time from where the rosbag was recorded, you have to append `--clock` to `rosbag play` so that it publishes simulated time in `/clock`, and well as set the param `use_time_time` before any other node starts in a fresh `roscore` instance.

There might not be a difference in `rospy.TIme(0)` and `rospy.Time()` because the default arguments are `0` anyway, [see API](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Time#Creating_Time_instances).

---

Originally posted by [Guess Giant](https://answers.ros.org/users/156073/guess-giant/) with karma: 26 on 2023-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1